Mancova or other method for this design of experiment challenge?
I'm working on a factorial experiment to optimize removal efficiency (Y) with two factors: velocity (A, 2 levels) and dose (B, 3 levels). I'm also considering water quality (M) as a covariate.
Due to operational constraints, I can only run experiments in pairs on two identical pilots. Each pair will have different velocity levels (A) but the same dose level (B). This means I can't fully randomize factor B. This means that i can run 2 treatments at once.
I'm wondering if MANCOVA is still appropriate for this design, or if there are alternative methods to account for the lack of complete randomization in factor B, like Generalized linear model or mixed model. I'm still new to Design of Experiments, so any guidance would be appreciated."
